# Combining Box Shadow and Text Gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients, box-shadow

Is there a possibilty to combine text gradient with box shadow?
See example-image to understand what exactly I want to achive.[Example-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vfba.png)

I've achived the Gradient, but the box shadow I added after, appears in foreground.
How can I solve that?

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#c93718 0%,#035b34 30%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 30px white;
}
```

Would love to get some help!

Thank's!
(I'm sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try multiple background:

```css
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:50px;
    color:transparent;
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(90deg,#c93718 0%,#035b34 30%),
      linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc);
    -webkit-background-clip: 
      text,
      padding-box;
    background-clip: 
      text,
      padding-box;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
}
```

```html
<h2>A title here</h2>
```

This won't work on Firefox due to a know bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1571244

As an alternative for Firefox, consider pseudo element:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #c93718 0%, #035b34 30%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>A title here</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked so far! :)
Now I've got to another problem: When I'm writing a mutated vowel, it's not showing up.. 
Is it possible to change the height of the padding box somehow?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user13017547 adjust `line-height` and make it bigger until you get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div and then you can play around with position will solve your issues.

```css
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#c93718 0%,#035b34 30%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: absolute;
    
}
div{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is Demo</h2>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
 I prefer making changes just in CSS, without changing the html...